# Reverse 'p4 where' command

Tags: perforce

The command ***p4 where*** shows the physical location of a file from its perforce path.

Is there a way to do the opposite: i.e. given a physical path (like */home/user/.../file.c*), ask p4 if it is mapped to the client view and get its perforce path (in the form of *//dev/user/.../file.c*) ?

I was thinking of doing a **p4 have** on the whole client then check if any result would match the path but that seems a bit tedious...

Comment: My deepest respect to the 'quality' standards algorithm which made me waste 30 mins trying to make this question acceptable. The inconcistency between the use of terms 'p4', 'perforce', the unecessary quotes and the erratic use of italic and boldness where necessary to be be able to ask this question.

Comment: Does 'p4 where /home/user/src/main/file.c' not work for you? It works for me.

Comment: ... yes it does. I misread the man page and tried complicated thing before the simple ones. That should be a lesson for me...

Comment: You should add an answer and accept it, would at least give others a quick answer should anyone google this.

Comment: You can also do `p4 have` on a particular file (using either depot or client syntax).  In cases where the client view has changed but the file has not been resynced, this will tell you the depot file that was originally synced (which will be different from where it is currently mapped).

Answer (score 1):

`p4 where <absolute path>` will give the path from depot.